# Swift: Extend a class with a where clause, to conform to a protocol

Tags: swift, extension-methods, swift-protocols

I am trying to extend a specific type of Array, so as to conform to an existing protocol.

```
extension Array where Element == Int : ProtocolX { }
```

But the compiler complains that

> Closure expression is unused

How do i go about implementing a protocol for a type with certain criteria?

Answer (score 3):

The protocol conformance needs to come before the `where` clause when you are declaring conditional conformance.

```
extension Array: ProtocolX where Element == Int { }
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks!